# My App crashes when I do an API call, cannot debug

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I am coming to this **contribution page** from homepage using 2 methods and do some operation on this page

1)

> window.open(url);

crashes when I click a button that calls a function that does an API call.

also somehow if I let the function run on the page load and there is no click involved; API is successfully called and the page doesn't crash.

2)
If I use,

> history.push(url);
> window.open(url, "_ self");

my page doesn't crash. But I cannot use this option to avoid crashing because I have to have my parent tab opened

> const url = `/documents/${itemId}?name=${item.title.replace(/ /g, "-")}&referrer=${encodeURIComponent(location?.pathname + location?.search)}`;

.
.
.

I used debugger everywhere, try catch blocks, but it enters react-dom-development.js and never comes back. Tab directly crashes, check storage, useEffects, states, props they all seems good

Comment: Kindly include your code block where this happens.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].